# html5 local file storage

Tags: html, offline, file-storage

I am in the process of building a webapp solely to be used on an iPad. The app is to be used internally, so I don't care about other devices. The app searches our online database of documents (PDFs) and presents a list of links to them.

So far so good.

I am now considering what happens if the user is not online for some reason. The best solution I can come up with is the user - when they ARE online - downloads the PDFs he will require and saves them locally.

What is the best way of doing this? I can pretty easily change the links to point to a page that contains a dynamically built manifest, but is this the best way to go? Is there a better way - perhaps using jQuery - to download and save files locally and access them from within the webapp?

Comment: How large will the files be in total that you want to cache clientside?

Comment: Are you referring to the FileSystem API, or localStorage? [localStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) is a key => value store not really intended for storing large amounts of data, and the [FileSystem API](http://dev.w3.org/2009/dap/file-system/pub/FileSystem/) isn't well established yet and doesn't appear to be included in even iOS 6 (see the ["what we're still waiting on"](http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/iphone-5-ios-6-html5-developers) section).

Comment: The users will need to clear their cache and download the documents they will need before each meeting. I suspect they will need to download around a couple of hundred megs of documents each time. Nothing too big. Is the document manifest part of the FileSystem API

Comment: This is all guesswork, you could do this kind of research on Google, I think this question isn't suited for SO.